# What is the proper way to deal with changing a single UIView within a storyboard scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Lets say I have a scene which includes a UIView container on the top half of the screen, and a UIView container on the bottom half of the screen and a few buttons at the very bottom of the screen.

Basically the bottom container will always display static text while the buttons across the bottom will change the content of the top container which may include an image, more buttons, or more text depending on what button is pressed on the bottom.  Also each time a bottom button is pressed the top container is transitioned to the new view with a flip from bottom transition.

I have achieved this purely programmatically, but decided to convert my app to a storyboard file since it makes producing the rest of my app much faster and simpler, plus makes the code not look like a crazy mess.

My limited understanding of storyboards seems to deduce that I would need a separate story board scene for every UIView change, and Apple's coding conventions with storyboards seem to imply that we should use a new ViewController every time you create a new scene.  All this adds up to an even bigger mess than I currently have.

Is there a better way of doing this?  Am I misunderstanding something?  If I am not confused, is there some way to make all these scene and view controller duplication cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storyboard editor makes it difficult to do what you're describing, because it doesn't let you edit freestanding views associated with a scene.

I suggest you just create a separate nib (not storyboard) for each of the top-half views.  These can exist separate from your storyboard.  Your view controller (which is instantiated from the storyboard) can then load whichever nib it needs when a button is pressed, and put the view from the nib into its (the view controller's) top-level view.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that would be the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

There must be a way!

I accidentally opened one one day (see attached image). Although I have no idea how I did it and really really want to know, I cannot reproduce it, nor close it. The UIView opened when I was dragging my connection for the table header view from the Connections Inspector to the list of controls on the left side of the screen (not to the actual UIViewController).

I too am reworking a project with storyboards and have a similar problem with multiple views per UIViewController.

In this case it is a table header. I have other UIViewControllers in the project with the same configuration but I cannot get them to pop up either.

[image]

Comment: If you drag from the code definition of an IBAction outlet and pause a moment while over a button in your standalone view it will flash and then open the view on the storyboard — at least prior to Xcode5. I've not figured out how to trigger this feature since upgrading to Xcode5 :( see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097854/showing-views-in-interface-builder-outside-viewcontroller-hierarchy-in-xcode5